# python p-value in OLS model and p-value from stats.linregress(), p-value from stats.ttest_ind() are different

Tags: python, scipy, p-value

I'm trying to see the p-value for an independent variable and a dependent variable. I fit a ols model and got the p-value as 0.001, then I used stats.linregress() function and got a p-value of 0.8022030591717838. Then I used stats.ttest_ind() function got a p-value of 5.9823075823729219e-32. 
Now I'm confused where did I do wrong? And which p-value is the correct one for me to make the decision on significace?
I checked a lot of documents on line and it seems the ols model one is the most common one to use, but there are also quite a few documnets used the second and third one. 
Can someone please provide me some hint on this?

Comment: Please include data sample and specifically how you call these methods, so we can reproduce.

Comment: `linregress` and `ttest_ind` are different tests, and their p-values are not associated with the same hypotheses.  For help with understanding these tests, you could ask over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).